# Run winforms application through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

Is there any way I use a desktop application based on forms on a server through an asp.net web page client side?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will be blocked by antivirus/antimalware solutions (even those from Microsoft).

You could start an aplication from browser IF using a kind of Plug-In, but in the last years that is exactly the way of malwares and viruses to damage computers. And because of it, evey security application (and even UAC and browsers themselves) are not allowing that kind of action.

You may risk put your solution into a plug-in and it be confused with viruses/malwares.